# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition Partition table

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-touch, phone

Can someone please provide me with the default partition table (a list , not the binary data ) for a Meizu Pro5  Ubuntu edition? After installing Ubuntu on an Android version, I am having OTA issues, which are always related to space problems on the cache partition, so I wanted to know the default size of the cache partition on Ubuntu edition Phones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the cache partition should be 700MiB [according to someone on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/help/meizu-pro5-32gb-64gb-partition-tables-t3460085) (they note that it is different to Android's allocation of 512 MiB to cache).

Here's the full partition table from them:

```
index=1,name=private,size=1MiB,start=0x400000,uuid=${uuid_private};
index=2,name=proinfo,size=256KiB,uuid=${uuid_proinfo};
index=3,name=misc,size=256KiB,uuid=${uuid_misc};
index=21,name=param,size=4MiB,start=0x800000,uuid=${uuid_param};
index=22,name=efs,size=8MiB,uuid=${uuid_efs};
index=23,name=pnv,size=2MiB,uuid=${uuid_pnv};
index=24,name=ldfw,size=4MiB,uuid=${uuid_ldfw};
index=25,name=dtb,size=4MiB,uuid=${uuid_dtb};
index=26,name=bootimg,size=24MiB,uuid=${uuid_bootimg};
index=27,name=recovery,size=32MiB,uuid=${uuid_recovery};
index=28,name=bootlogo,size=32MiB,uuid=${uuid_bootlogo};
index=29,name=rstinfo,size=20MiB,uuid=${uuid_rstinfo};
index=30,name=mnv,size=20MiB,uuid=${uuid_mnv};
index=31,name=reserved1,size=20MiB,uuid=${uuid_reserved1};
index=32,name=reserved2,size=20MiB,uuid=${uuid_reserved2};
index=33,name=reserved3,size=20MiB,uuid=${uuid_reserved3};
index=41,name=system,size=2560MiB,start=0x10000000,uuid=${uuid_system};
index=42,name=custom,size=512MiB,uuid=${uuid_custom};
index=43,name=cache,size=700MiB,uuid=${uuid_cache};
index=44,name=userdata,size=0,uuid=${uuid_userdata};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the df (-h) command to see, how the internal storage is divided into which partitions and which space is left.